# How to get get Records based on multiple columns from a table

Tags: sql

Consider the following table.

[image]

From the above table I want to select the Middle BFS_SCORE per LN_LOAN_ID and BR_ID. There are some LN_LOAN_ID with single score.

As an example for the above table the output I need is as below.

[image]

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: What database are you using? Also, you probably need a median, not the "middle" bfs_score.

Comment: What happens in the case where there are 2 BR_ID's per LN_LOAN_ID and not an odd number as you have shown in the example above.

Comment: @KamilG., I am using SQL 2012. I can't use meadin of the scores. The requirement is to get the middle score if there is more than 2 scores, and use the least score when there is 2 score.

Comment: @woodhead92, If there are 2 BR_ID's per LN_LOAN_ID then I've to get the middle score for each each BR_ID. There could be a chance in either of the BR_ID is not exists in the table.

Comment: @jambai What about the case when there are an even number of BFS scores (4 and above)?

Answer (score 0):

To handle cases where there are two scores for unique pair of `LN_LOAD_ID, BR_ID` you need a **median**, as there is no middle value for `BFS_SCORE`.

---

**Postgres** solution:

Create a median aggregate function following [Postgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _final_median(NUMERIC[])
   RETURNS NUMERIC AS
$$
   SELECT AVG(val)
   FROM (
     SELECT val
     FROM unnest($1) val
     ORDER BY 1
     LIMIT  2 - MOD(array_upper($1, 1), 2)
     OFFSET CEIL(array_upper($1, 1) / 2.0) - 1
   ) sub;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;

CREATE AGGREGATE median(NUMERIC) (
  SFUNC=array_append,
  STYPE=NUMERIC[],
  FINALFUNC=_final_median,
  INITCOND='{}'
);
```

Then your query would look as simple as this:

```
select 
  ln_load_id,
  median(bfs_score) as bfs_score
  br_id
from yourtable
```

But the tricky part comes with `score_order`. If there are two pairs and you actually really need a median, not the middle value - then there will be no row for your calculated score, so it will be null. Other than that, join back to your table to retrieve it for the "middle" column:

```
select 
  t1.ln_load_id, t1.bfs_score, t1.br_id, t2.score_order
from (
  select 
    ln_load_id,
    median(bfs_score) as bfs_score
    br_id
  from yourtable
  ) t1
  left join yourtable t2 on
    t1.ln_load_id = t2.ln_load_id
    and t1.br_id = t2.br_id
    and t1.bfs_score = t2.bfs_score
```